# Finding the optimal value for a dual problem in optimization

Tags: optimization, duality-theorems, non-convex-optimization

Consider the following optimization problem: 
\begin{align*}
&\min_{x_1,x_2 \in \mathbb{R}}x_1x_2\\
&\text{Subject to } x_1^2 + x_2^2\le 1, x_1\ge 0, x_2 \ge 0\\
\end{align*}
I have been tasked with find the optimal value of the dual problem here. The definition for the optimal value of the dual problem that I have been given is 
$$d^* = \max_{\vec{\lambda} \in \mathbb{R}^m, \vec{\lambda} \ge 0} g(\vec{\lambda})$$
where $$g(\vec{\lambda}) = \inf_{\vec{x}\in D}\bigg(x_1x_2 + \lambda_1 (x_1^2+x_2^2-1)-\lambda_2x_1-\lambda_3x_2\bigg)$$
and $D$ is the domain under consideration. Here, $D$ is $\mathbb{R}^2$.

NOTE: Normally $g$ is a function of $\lambda$ and $\mu$, but since there are no equality constraints, this is just a function of $\lambda$.

My issue here is I have no idea how to find $g(\vec{\lambda})$, much less how to find the maximum over all $\vec{\lambda} \in \mathbb{R}^3$. Are there any steps that I should consider here? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You've misunderstood the relationship between the constraints that have been handled in the Lagrangian and the domain $D$.  Since the constraints that force $x$ to be in the upper right section of the unit disk have been incorporated into the Lagrangian they don't have to be incorporated into the domain.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I follow. Do you mean that my interpretation of $D$ is incorrect? If so, what should it be?

Comment: Try $D=R^{2}$.  Random text added for length...

Comment: Note Brian's comment: The $\inf$ should be over all $x$.

Comment: Find conditions under when the $\inf$ is finite. This will give the dual constraints.

Comment: Okay, I have edited my problem to adjust $D$, but even with that fix, I'm still not entirely sure how I can find $g(\lambda)$. No matter which $x$ I consider, I get a function of $\lambda$, and I am not sure how to minimize that.

Comment: Write $g$ as the $\inf$ of a quadratic in $x$. Find conditions on $x$ such that $g$ has a finite $\inf$.

Comment: @copper.hat Just to clarify, when you say "write $g$ as the inf of a quadratic in $x$," you mean write it as $x^T A x$, where $x^T = (x_1 \ x_2)$?

Comment: @BSplitter: Yup

Comment: I believe I can write the argument of the infimum as $x^T\begin{pmatrix}\lambda_1 & \frac{1}{2} \\ \frac{1}{2} &\lambda_1\end{pmatrix} x - (\lambda_2 \ \lambda_3) \begin{pmatrix}x_1 \\ x_2\end{pmatrix} - \lambda_1$. Could I find the infimum of this quadratic function by taking the gradient and setting it equal to zero?

Comment: Yes. Remember that you will then take the $\sup$ of $g$ over the relevant $\lambda$. Note that if $\lambda_1<{1 \over 2}$ then $g$ is $-\infty$ and if $\lambda_1={1 \over 2}$, then if $\lambda_2 \neq \lambda_3$ then  $g$ is $-\infty$. The result will be a messy expression for $g$ with conditions on $\lambda$ such that $g$ is finite. Then find the $\sup$ of the result. (In other words, you need only take the $\sup$ over $\lambda_1 \ge {1 \over 2}$, and if $\lambda_1 = {1 \over 2}$ we must also have $\lambda_2 = \lambda_3$.)

Comment: If my computations are correct, I believe the dual value is $- { 1\over 2}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for additional conditions on $\lambda$ such that $g$ is finite.

It is a little easier to do if we write $g$ as a quadratic.

Let $S= {1 \over 2} \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ (note the eigenvalues are $\pm {1 \over 2}$), then
$g(\lambda) = \inf_x x^T (\lambda_1 I + S) x -(\lambda_2, \lambda_3)^T x -\lambda_1$.

Note that we need $\lambda_1 \ge {1 \over 2}$, as otherwise the $\inf$ is $-\infty$.

If $\lambda_1 = {1 \over 2}$, we can choose $x_2 = -x_1$, and then we can see that if $\lambda_2 \neq \lambda_3$, then the $\inf$ is $-\infty$. Hence if $\lambda_1 = {1 \over 2}$
we must have $\lambda_2 = \lambda_3$ in order to have a finite $g$.

If $\lambda_1 > {1 \over 2}$ then we see that the minimising $x$ satisfies
$x = {1 \over 2} (\lambda_1 I + S)^{-1} \begin{bmatrix} \lambda_2 \\ \lambda_3 \end{bmatrix}$,
and so $g(\lambda) = -{1 \over 4} \begin{bmatrix} \lambda_2 & \lambda_3 \end{bmatrix}(\lambda_1 I + S)^{-1} \begin{bmatrix} \lambda_2 \\ \lambda_3 \end{bmatrix} -\lambda_1 < -{1 \over 2}$.

If $\lambda_1 = {1 \over 2}$ and $\lambda_2 = \lambda_3$, then we can write 
$x^T (\lambda_1 I + S) x -(\lambda_2, \lambda_3)^T x = {1 \over 2} (e^T x)^2 - \lambda_2 (e^T x)$, where $e$ is the vector of ones. In particular, the $\min$ occurs when $e^T x = \lambda_2$ and hence
$g(\lambda) = -{1 \over 2}\lambda_2^2 -{1 \over 2} \le - {1\over 2}$.

Hence $d^*=\sup_{\lambda \ge 0} g(\lambda) = - { 1\over 2}$.

Comment: I apologize for not responding sooner; I haven't had a chance to look at this problem until today. Correct me if I'm wrong, but in the $\lambda_1>\frac{1}{2}$ case, wouldn't $g(\lambda) = -\lambda_1$, since the first and second terms of $g(\lambda)$ would cancel out? I still agree with the conclusion.

Comment: @BSplitter: I think you might be missing a factor of ${1 \over 2}$ so it doesn't exactly cancel. (Of course, I am prone to making mistakes!)

Comment: I wrote it out slightly differently. I just called the matrix in question $M$, and its inverse $M^{-1}$. Then the minimizing $x$ would be $M^{-1} \begin{bmatrix}\lambda_2 \\ \lambda_3\end{bmatrix}$. Plugging that in allows some cancellation, I think.